# Nested ForEach loop running incredibly slowly

Tags: powershell, active-directory, data-cleaning

I have written a script That is designed to search an OU for all the users contained whiten. it then gets all groups that that user it finds are members of, and if the DistinguishedName of a group is found to match a string it will remove thate user from that group specifically.

However it is incredibly slow taking anywhere from 5-45 seconds an entry. is this normal or is there any way for me to expedite it?

```
$OUs = "OU=Terminated,OU=####,OU=####,DC=####,DC=####"

foreach ($ou in $OUs) 
{
  $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter * 
  foreach ($user in $users)
  {
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User | ? {$_.distinguishedName -like "*Groups_I_Want_Removed*" }
      foreach($group in $groups) 
      {
         Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $group -whatif    
      }
  }
}

$results = foreach ($OU in $OUs) 
{
    get-aduser -SearchBase $OU -filter * -Properties MemberOf | ? MemberOf -like "*Distribution Lists*"
}
$results | Export-Csv .\Output_of_users_remaining.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My concern is that this script is going through thousands of users and the last time I ran it it was unable to finish within 3 hours and I stopped it at the end of the day. in that time it said it had corrected about 5000~ish users.

Comment: Use runspaces and let the inner loop run in parallel

Comment: Have you done anything to narrow down what exact part is slow? Can be as simple as just adding `Write-Host "[$(Get-Date -format 'HH:mm:ss.fff')] Removing $user from $group"` inside the inner loop and inspect the discrepancy in time stamps

Comment: I have not, I can see that there is about 30 seconds on average between entries but i believe it is do too the two lists calling back to each other.

Comment: Also Runspaces are a new concept to me. I'm looking into it but im only getting a vague idea of how to implement it.

Comment: piping to `Where-Object` [you used the alias `?`] is slow. the cmdlet is slow AND shoving things across the pipeline is slow. have you tried replacing those calls with `$Collection.Where({your-filter-stuff-here})`?